# qPython Functional Queries

Tags: kdb

We are trying to build functional queries using qPython. Strating with simple examples to build where conditions at the run time.
we defined a q function on out KDB server like

```
fn:{[c]
    t: (select from tbl);
    :?[t;c;0b;()];
}
```

in Python we open a connection and send the condition

```
c = [['=', numpy.string_('TradeId'), 123456]]
result = conn.sendSync('fn', c)
```

when I do this, in q console I see that = operator as "=". 
the question is how to pass operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `value` the string/char on the kdb side to convert it from a string/char to the underlying kdb operator. This works in your example but you might need some extra work/testing to generalise it to all possible operators that you might send:

```
q)tbl:([]TradeId:0 123456 123456 123456;col2:1 2 3 4)
q)fn:{[c] c:.[c;(::;0);value];t:(select from tbl); :?[t;c;0b;()];}

q)0(`fn;enlist("=";`TradeId;123456))
TradeId col2
------------
123456  2
123456  3
123456  4

q)0(`fn;(("=";`TradeId;123456);("in";`col2;2 4)))
TradeId col2
------------
123456  2
123456  4
```

Note - Im using `0()` to send requests within kdb itself but this should be the equivalent of sending from qPython. The bit you need to change is the `c:.[c;(::;0);value];` in your kdb function

Comment: your solution works, but could you share the generalized form for a array of operators. Also since I am new to Q would you mind explaining what the line above does

Comment: It's hard to generalise without knowing the full range of filters that you might use. The solution I gave above already generalises to single or multiple filters of the form `("string of kdb function/operator";columnName;filter)`. As for the explanation, the dot `.` is a dot amend (aka amend at depth), the `(::;0)` means at index zero of all top-level items in the array, and finally `value` on a string returns the kdb object inside the string

Answer (score 1):

@terrylynch answer works
for specifically qPython

from python sending works

```
 c = [[ qtype.QLambda( '{x in  y}'), numpy.string_('TradeId'), [123, 456,789]]]
```